# GAE Java Search API: What's the acceptable range for QueryOptions.Builder.setLimit(int)

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

Apparently the default query limit on the number of returned documents is currently 20. Changing it is possible by using [`QueryOptions.Builder.setLimit()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/search/QueryOptions.Builder#setLimit%28int%29). Java dev docs don't seem to indicate the allowed maximum.

I have thousands of records indexed in my application and searches might potentially return a large number of objects. Instead of hardcoding something like `MAX_QUERY_RESULTS = 1000` in the app, is there a way to programmatically access this search quota?

Comment: You just want to get this constant from search api? Why not to use something like: from google.appengine.api import search; print search.MAXIMUM_SEARCH_OFFSET

Comment: @DmitrySadovnychyi apologies: I should have made it clear that this is about the Java Search API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class com.google.appengine.api.search.checkers.SearchApiLimits has a long list of constants of this ilk, including SEARCH_MAXIMUM_LIMIT with the value 1000.